# Is there any way to access the managed debugger in a Visual Studio package

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to write a Visual Studio package that shows a live object graph during debugging.

Is there any way to access the data of the managed debugger from within a VS 2010 package? I am aware of the EnvDTE.Debugger API, but this does not provide enough data for my use cases.

I do know it is possible using WinDbg/SOS, but this is not an option for me as I want to be able to use it nicely integrated.

I really appreciate any information!

Edit:

My requirements basically are those:

1. Get all objects of the current stackframe when the debugger is in break mode.
2. Get all objects referenced by a given object (i.e. its fields).
3. Uniquely identify an object so that when several objects reference the same object there is a way to detect that its just one object that is referenced.
4. Do all this while the VS debugger is attached, that effectively kills using another debugger...

What I found out so far:

- EnvDTE.Debugger does not fulfill requirement 2 and 3
- A debugger visualizer does not work because it does oly work on serializable objects
- WinDbg does not work as it needs to be exclusively attached to the process.

Comment: My apologies. I misread it as you wanted to attach the debugger for some reason. Doh'. Deleted my irrelevant answer.

Comment: "but this does not provide enough data for my use cases" - could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Have you seen this thread about Debugger Visualizers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959048/debugger-visualizer-and-type-is-not-marked-as-serializable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in Simon Mouriers comment, I will go for the [manually serialized Debugger Visualizer approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959048/debugger-visualizer-and-type-is-not-marked-as-serializable).

This is the only reasonable way to do what I want to do, although I did not fully verify it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of... If I understand your requirements correctly this is a tough call - you will have to somehow combine `EnvDTE.Debugger` with [`Debugger5`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte100.debugger5.aspx) and [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) (which comes with source code!):

- [David Broman's CLR Profiling API Blog: CLRProfiler V4 Released](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032249/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released)
- [CLR Inside Out - Profiling the .NET Garbage-Collected Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309515.aspx)
- [CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4 is now available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2011/02/02/clr-profiler-for-net-framework-4-is-now-available.aspx)